# GPG: How to delete bad session key and get asked for encryption password again?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, gpg-signature, gpg-agent, geocaching

I tried to solve this Geocache:

https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC67EXW_signaturbruch

And it gave me a password prompt, when I tried to solve `gpg message.asc`, but I didn't know the correct password back then.

Now I know it, but it just wouldn't give me the password prompt again, no matter how I tried it.

The output is as follows:

```
Martinas-Air:gpg martl$ gpg message.asc
gpg: WARNING:  Kein Kommando angegeben.  Versuche zu raten was gemeint ist ...
gpg: CAST5 verschlüsselte Daten
gpg: Verschlüsselt mit einer Passphrase
gpg: Entschlüsselung fehlgeschlagen: Bad session key
```

(I am on a German MacOs Mojave, 10.14.6 and my `gpg --version` gives me this:

```
Martinas-Air:gpg martl$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.17
libgcrypt 1.8.4
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/martl/.gnupg
Unterstützte Verfahren:
Öff. Schlüssel: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Verschlü.: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
           CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Komprimierung: nicht komprimiert, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2)
```

Can somebody tell me, how can I get back to getting asked for the password again??? I searched whole Internet for solutions like "restart your computer", reinstall all gpg tools, delete all .gpg files and so on, but nothing would make it better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After having had the same issue, I was able to get the password prompt back using the following steps:

In file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, append:

```
use-agent
pinentry-mode loopback
```

In file `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, append:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
allow-loopback-pinentry
```

Then restart your gpg agent with `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`.